# Trying to start a new activity and pass a String with a ListActivity

Tags: android

I am making a simple Browser and i am trying to make a favorites page.

So far, I created a HomePage class which has the code:

```
package com.example.browser3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Browser;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
// Indicates that Lint should ignore the specified warnings for the annotated
// element.
public class HomePage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

WebView ourBrow; // create a WebView object
EditText url; // create an EditText object
String theWebsite;
String theHomePage;


public String getTheHomePage() {
    return theHomePage;
}


public void setTheHomePage(String theHomePage) {
    this.theHomePage = theHomePage;
}






public String readFile(String fileName,String a){
    try {
        InputStream in=openFileInput(fileName);
        if(in!=null){
            InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buffreader= new BufferedReader(reader);

            StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
            String str;
            while((str=buffreader.readLine())!=null){
                builder.append(str+ "\n");

                a= builder.toString();
            }
            in.close();

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return a;

}



  public void writeFile(String fileName, String x){

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName,MODE_APPEND));
        out.write(x+"\n");

        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ourBrow.loadUrl(theHomePage);
super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // onCreate is called
                                                        // in order to initialize(Start)
                                                        // our activity.
                                                        // 
                                                        // This is where
                                                        // most
                                                        // initialization
                                                        // goes
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Derived class onCreate(bundle)
                                        // method must call super class
                                        // implementation of this method. If
                                        // you do not then an exception will
                                        // be thrown SuperNotCalledException
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); // Set the activity content from
                                            // a layout resource using
                                            // findViewById to interact with
                                            // widgets

    ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser); // finds the webView
                                                        // identified in
                                                        // fragment_main by
                                                        // the id
                                                        // "wvBrowser"
    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enables JavaScript
    ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); // Zooms out the
                                                            // page for easy
                                                            // navigation
    ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); // Allow us to set the
                                                    // normal view point.
                                                    // Not to be too small
                                                    // or too big for the
                                                    // screen
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient()); // Overrides the
                                                    // emulator's browser
                                                    // because it can
                                                    // interfere with this
                                                    // one
    try {
        ourBrow.loadUrl(readFile("home.txt",theHomePage)); // We must throw and catch
                                                    // an exception for
                                                    // example when it
                                                    // cannot load because
                                                    // it doesn't have
                                                    // Internet
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGo); // Set buttons from
                                                    // fragment_main with
    Button menu= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMenu);                                         // different IDs
    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
    Button forw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bForward);
    Button ref = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRefresh);


    url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tUrl); // Finds the text identified
                                                // in fragment_main by the
    menu.setOnClickListener(this);                                          // id "tUrl"
    go.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    ref.setOnClickListener(this); // Registers a callback to be invoked when
                                    // this view is clicked
    forw.setOnClickListener(this);

}
private void clickHome(){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.browser3.MENU"));
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { // This function is called when a view is
                                // clicked
    switch (v.getId()) { // Used to identify the view by id
    case R.id.bMenu:
        clickHome();

    case R.id.bGo:



         theWebsite = url.getText().toString(); // Returns the text
                                                        // which textView is
                                                        // displaying as an
                                                        // identical String
                                                        // in the variable
                                                        // theWebsite
        writeFile("history.txt", theWebsite);

        ourBrow.loadUrl(theWebsite); // Loads the given Url, in our case
                                        // (thewebsite)
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); // We
                                                                                                        // set
                                                                                                        // up
                                                                                                        // our
                                                                                                        // inputManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(url.getWindowToken(), 0); // We use the
                                                                // method
                                                                // that will
                                                                // hide our
                                                                // keyboard
        break;
    case R.id.bBack:
        if (ourBrow.canGoBack()) // Gets whether the WebView has a back
                                    // history item
            ourBrow.goBack(); // Goes back in the history of the WebView.
        break;
    case R.id.bForward:
        if (ourBrow.canGoForward()) // Gets whether the WebView has a
                                    // forward history item.
            ourBrow.goForward(); // Goes forward in the history of the
                                    // WebView.
        break;
    case R.id.bRefresh:
        ourBrow.reload(); // Reloads the current URL.
        break;
    }

}


}
```

and a ListActivity class with the code:

```
package com.example.browser3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Favorite2 extends ListActivity {

String[] elements={"http://www.yahoo.com","http://www.facebook.com"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
HomePage object=new HomePage();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Favorite2.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , elements));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.browser3.HomePage");// ce e aici aia porneste la click
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Favorite2.this , ourClass);
    String s=elements[position];
    object.ourBrow.loadUrl(s);
    startActivity(ourIntent);


            }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

All I want is when i click one of the ListActivity members in the Favorite2 class, to start the HomePage activity and to take the name, which is a String in the String array elements and to load it in the webview or just to enter it in the EditText named url. 
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Add it as an extra to your intent:

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Favorite2.this , ourClass);
ourIntent.putExtra("name", your_string);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

And in your activity get the extra and set it to your EditText:

```
url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tUrl); // Finds the text identified
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
if (name != null) {
    url.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: when i get the extra, where do i put that code? in a new method or in the onCreate? I already tried that earlier in a new method, but i think i messed up.

Comment: @PetrescuRadu-Tiberiu You can get the extras in `onCreate`. Like in the code I've shown it's done after you find your `EditText` view.

Comment: and if i add it in the onCreate method, won't it use it whenever i open the HomePage Activity?

Comment: @PetrescuRadu-Tiberiu as you see i've added a null check, so if it's null (if opened not by the fragment) it won't use it.

Comment: @PetrescuRadu-Tiberiu glad it solved your problem :)